# How to match a string with specific characters

Tags: python, regex, string

How can I match a string that ends with $ using regular expressions?

> History of America$ or History of Korea$ or UK$

I want to match ignoring anything else other than ending with $

I tried

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\w\$')
if pattern.findall(s):
    print('Found')
else
    print('Not found')
```

but I think the white space is giving me an error.
what should I do?

Comment: You can check for a space as well `[\w ]+\$`

Comment: When developing regular expressions, I like to use an online regex tester to test it with various input strings. There are several good ones available, if you just search.

Comment: re.findall returns a list of strings. Apart from the missing `:` after else, what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
( # match group
  \w+ # match one or more AZ-az
  \$ # must end with $
)
```

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+\$)')
if pattern.findall(s):
    print('Found')
else
    print('Not found')
```

If you want to add numbers, use ([\w\d]+$)

Comment: Note that `\w` also matches `\d`